# Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function error on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, autocomplete

I have a console message of "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function (index):29(anonymous function) (index):29jQuery.extend.ready jquery.js:387DOMContentLoaded jquery.js:722" - I am tying to get an autocomplete to work. I have googled this for about an hour :(. I only have one reference to JQuery, I have reference to the autocomplete css. Any Help Would be appreciated.

My HTML:

```
<title>MyTITLE</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="autocomplete/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="autocomplete/jquery.autocomplete.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="autocomplete/jquery.autocomplete.css" />


<link href="templates/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<link href="templates/css/plugins/metisMenu/metisMenu.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<link href="templates/css/sb-admin-2.css" rel="stylesheet">

<link href="templates/font-awesome-4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<script type="text/javascript"> $(document).ready(function(){  $("#customer_name").autocomplete("autocomplete/customer.php", {      selectFirst: true   }) }); </script>

    <input type="text" value="" id="customer_name" name="customer_name" class="form-control" placeholder="Place Customer Here">
```

I Have attached a picture of the error in the console.
Thank You for All of Your Help

[image: Error]

Comment: Your `jquery.autocomplete.js` did not load or there is something different in it. BTW, where is your `<body>` tag? `<input>` cannot be in the head.

Comment: autocomplete is not defined did you include the required jquery ui javascript library ? have a look at the working example it may help --> http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Comment: I combined the text because I have a lot of other html between the head and the text input. I placed in the jquery.autocomplete.js an alert() function on load and it popped up. I tried two different jquery.autocomplete.js files from the jquery website too.

Comment: @Pranav C Balan That Didn't Work It gave me a compile error a Unexpected ":", expected one of: "}"